# Rate of área change according to its diameter

Tags: derivatives, area

The area A of a circle is related to its diameter by the equation `A=πD²/4`. At which rate approximatelly the area vary in relation to its diameter when D = 10m?

Comment: What are your efforts in solving. Please share them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rate of change of the area with respect to the diameter is just the derivative $\frac{dA}{dD}$. Computing this we get:

$$
\frac{dA}{dD}=\frac{\pi D}{2}
$$

At $D=10$m the area is changing at the rate:

$$
\left. \frac{dA}{dD} \right|_{D=10}=\frac{\pi \cdot 10}{2}=5\pi\approx 15.7\text{ m}^2/\text{m}
$$